# redefining global symbol: pi error while ceating a launch file

Tags: ros

created a launch file where my robot should open on the gazebo world and when in try to run the launch file using roslaunch i get the following error

```
redefining global symbol: pi
when processing file: /home/akash/project/src/techman_robot_ros-master/tm_grasp_description/urdf/tm700.urdf.xacro
included from: /home/akash/project/src/techman_robot_ros-master/tm_grasp_description/urdf/tm700_robot.urdf.xacro
xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
started roslaunch server http://akash:37109/
```

still i can see my gazebo world but cannot see the robot imported.

and this was the launch file

```
<launch>
  <arg name="eih" default="false" />
  <arg name="limited" default="false"/>

  <group unless="$(arg eih)">
    <param unless="$(arg limited)" name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find tm_grasp_description)/urdf/tm700_robot.urdf.xacro'" />
        <param if="$(arg limited)" name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find tm_grasp_description)/urdf/tm700_robot_joint_limited.urdf.xacro'" />
      </group>
      <group if="$(arg eih)">
    <param unless="$(arg limited)" name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find tm_grasp_description)/urdf/tm700_robot_eih.urdf.xacro'" />
    <param if="$(arg limited)" name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find tm_grasp_description)/urdf/tm700_robot_joint_limited_eih.urdf.xacro'" />
  </group>
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
        <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
        <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
            <arg name="world_name" 
                 value="$(find tm700_moveit_config)/launch/gg.world"/>


</include>

</launch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ROS Jade [Xacro internally uses functions and constants from Python `math` module such as `pi`](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Math_expressions) when converting a Xacro to a URDF robot description. It seems like [`tm700.urdf.xacro`](https://github.com/JuFengWu/techman_robot_ros/blob/master/tm_grasp_description/urdf/tm700.urdf.xacro) (and several other Xacro-files in the package) for some reason has `pi` defined in line 8

```
<property name="pi" value="3.14159265" />
```

which is in conflict with the existing definition from the math module. Therefore the generation of your robot description fails. **Delete all the definitions of `pi` from the Xacro-files**, then it should work.

Comment: Thanks that solved the error message but still i could not see my robot in gazebo

Comment: @Akash Did you resolve that by yourself or do you still need help with it? Have you more information (maybe a screenshot of what happens)?